# WebSocket connection to 'wss://...' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: ssl, websocket

I have a pretty stange error:

I was trying to test live chat made on websockets, but when the scripts loaded, I get this message in developer tools window:
"WebSocket connection to 'wss://chat.mywebsite.com:80/testuser@wr94@34@0: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED"

The error message in developer tools sends me to this line of code:
wrc_socket = new WebSocket(_wsServerUrl+'/'+login+'@wr94@'+_id+'@'+_userType);

I was trying to figure out this issue with chat developers, and we found, that this issue is only happening on my computer where I'm working.

Same browsers, same network, same OS - I have the issue, everyone else don't have it. Apperently, something installed on my computer that blocks wss connections. But I can't figure out what exactly. Tryed disabling antivirus and windows firewall, no result.

I've tested with chrome, firefox and opera (all letest versions). When installed on my computer - they reproduce this error, when installed on collegue's computer (he sist just next to me in the same office) error not happening.

Also, I've tried this on my home computer and got even more strange result: Opera and Firefox reproduse the issue, and Chrome works fine.

Can you give me a hint or a direction to investigate this? I think it's related to certificates stuff, but don't know where to start.

Answer (score 5):

> wss://chat.mywebsite.com:80/

I'm pretty sure that you don't have `wss://` configured on port 80. Port 80 is used by default for plain HTTP, i.e. `http://` and `ws://` and not `https://` and `wss://`. If the latter is available at all depends on your server configuration but simply trying `wss://` on a port configured only for `ws://` will not work.

If this works for other maybe they do it differently, that is they either use `ws://chat.example.com` or `wss://chat.example.com` but not `wss://chat.example.com:80`.

Comment: That doesn't explains why I got this message in two of three browsers on a same computer. It must be something related to browser and it's configuration

Comment: upd: I checked network log in browsers that don't reproduce this error:
they ARE connect through "wss://chat.example.com:80" with both "wss://" and ":80"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Opera, but Firefox has its own certificate store and won't trust a certificate because the OS trusts.